# Edits requested by a user were performed, but another user is listed as the question's editor

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56216648/revisions) that, in my view, could have been much clearer with the help of a few edits.  I clicked the edit button, reworded the title for (what I believe to be) a significant clarity improvement, improved some of the wording in the body of the post, and added code markup where appropriate.  I then submitted the edit for peer review.

Not second later, I refreshed the page so see that all of my edits had been adopted.  However, as I went to answer the question, I noticed the 'edited by' tag indicated another user.  Now, I care absolutely not at all who gets 'credit' for an approved edit, but this has raised my curiosity.

Is it possible the other editor made the EXACT same changes I did moments beforehand?  Maybe, I guess, but that seems to border quite closely to impossibility.

Furthermore, an examination of the edit history thereof shows just two edits excluding mine. Now, again, I couldn't possibly care less whose name is listed, and I'm sure I'm missing something with regard to this functionality.  However, I would be interested in any information that could explain this.

Comment: Are you sure no additional changes were performed? It sounds like someone reviewed your suggested edit and chose "improve edit". Did you get the +2 rep for the edit?

Comment: No, I'm not sure.  Have you found the post in my history, and if so would you be so kind as to point me to what you're seeing?

I did not get +2 but that matters little if at all.  Just curious.

Comment: No, I haven't found it nor I have looked for it. Would be easier if you provided a link for the post.

Comment: @yivi the revision history can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56216648/revisions

Comment: Your edit is still [pending](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23058221). The other edit came before yours.

Comment: Oops, thank you.  Will delete the post.

Comment: Btw, you can see the status of your edit suggestions on your profile [under suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: That question is also of rather low quality, and should probably be closed.

Comment: Without more detail yes, but i simply chose to edit instead of report.

Comment: You shouldn't submit suggested edit for low quality / off-topic questions unless your edit improves the question to the point it no longer merits closure.

Comment: I've now provided a viable answer to the question and do not believe it should be closed.  But that is not the point here.

Answer (score 3):

The question you mentioned in your post was edited by a user with more than 2000 reputation points with the [edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). [They edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56216648/2) and their edit was applied before [your edit could get peer-reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23058221) (peer-reviewing takes time)

When a question has a suggested edit pending review, no more edits are allowed until this suggested edit is reviewed (either accepted or rejected).

For more information see [how editing works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: I see that now.  That is counterproductive in this case but not terribly consequential; regardless I have no interest in reaching that level of reputation.

Comment: @C.Peck it's not counterproductive, reputation is how the community thanks you. People having more reputation are allowed certain privileges which benefit them from low rep users like me. It is believed that people with high rep pose close proximity to better editing questions but still we are given an edit button which then the edits are  peer-reviewed and then applied

Comment: I absolutely understand the principle, I just find this case to be objectively counterproductive since a more thorough edit was replaced by something less clear and with very little added value. Oh well.

Comment: In response to your latest edit, there is either a bug or no other pending edit existed since I was able to initiate and save just fine.  Regardless, I feel ready to finish this exercise in futility.

Comment: If the current version of the question poses some more mistakes and typos that can be fixed, feel free to edit the question again but I don't think the OP provided much information to the community.

Comment: I will respectfully disagree with your first point.

Comment: Even if the information was enough, they should try to solve it by themselves first and share their approach. They cannot just put the error in the question ask to fix it

Comment: Ideally yes, but I do not see any harm in providing a potential answer if one is readily available. My opinion is that many such requirements are simultaneously excessively strict and quite harmful to the communication and gathering of information, but I do not have or want any official say in these matters.  Carry on.